# Different results from SAS PROC MIXED procedure and R lme function

Tags: r, mixed-model, sas

I have 3(treatment)x3(period)x6(sequence) crossover design data. I have used SAS PROC MIXED procedure and I got the results with following code:

```
data cross;
input yield id treatment period sequence;
cards;
72  1   1   1   1
73  1   2   2   1
77  1   3   3   1
75  2   2   1   2
78  2   3   2   2
70  2   1   3   2
75  3   3   1   3
77  3   1   2   3
73  3   2   3   3
64  4   1   1   4
68  4   3   2   4
71  4   2   3   4
80  5   2   1   5
72  5   1   2   5
80  5   3   3   5
74  6   3   1   6
76  6   2   2   6
70  6   1   3   6
58  7   1   1   4
62  7   3   2   4
67  7   2   3   4
64  8   2   1   5
56  8   1   2   5
60  8   3   3   5
72  9   3   1   6
69  9   2   2   6
66  9   1   3   6
76  10  2   1   2
79  10  3   2   2
65  10  1   3   2
61  11  1   1   1
50  11  2   2   1
60  11  3   3   1
71  12  3   1   3
72  12  1   2   3
75  12  2   3   3
;
PROC MIXED data=cross;
CLASSES id treatment period sequence;
MODEL yield= sequence period treatment period*treatment / solution;
RANDOM id(sequence);
*lsmeans period/alpha=0.05 cl diff adjust=tukey;
run;
```

Results:

```
               Effect              DF      DF    F Value    Pr > F

               sequence             5       6       0.88    0.5479
               period               2      16       0.24    0.7863
               treatment            2      16       7.23    0.0058
               treatment*period     4      16       3.32    0.0368
```

But when I used `lme` function from `nlme` package in R, I got the following results:

R code:

```
anova(cross <- lme(yield ~ sequence +treatment + period + period*treatment,data=cross, random= ~1|id/sequence,correlation=NULL,method="REML"))
```

Results:

```
               numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)        1    16 1086.7422  <.0001
sequence           5     6    0.5755  0.7196
treatment          2    16    7.2270  0.0058
period             2    16    0.2441  0.7863
treatment:period   4    16    3.3186  0.0368
```

The results are same for treatment, period and treatment-period interaction but I got different results for sequence. And I don't know why? Has anyone got any idea?